Calculating percentage of land cover type within a buffer
I am trying to calculate the percentage of each land cover type (raster data) within a buffer area in ArcGIS.
So far I have attempted to use the summarize within function. This appears to work but I have to convert the land cover raster into a polygon inorder to do the analysis. The results include a land area measurement in m^2 which I am assuming is the land area measure of that land cover, is this correct?
Is there a better method for accomplishing this goal? Perhaps one that allows the data to remain as a raster?

Do you have Spatial Analyst extension?

Tabulate area will give you accurate approximation

Yes I have the spatial analyst extension

Try Zonal Statistics
